# How to forward certain ports on my domain to another IP

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, port, forwarding

I have one domain name with MX Record all pointing to a single public IP. However, I have different servers which all should use the same domain on different public IPs. Since all of the traffic to my domain comes on a single IP, I want to forward some of it (based on port) to the other IPs. My services include email server, SIP server, apache, etc. I am using Ubuntu 10 server edition on all machines.

I guess I will need to set up some kind of proxy/firewall to do this. I also think that I will need to keep the originating IPs of the clients which access those services, so the router will need to rewrite the IP addresses in both directions so that my clients all use the same IP and all is transparant to them.

What kind of setup can you recommend me for this thing? Do I need a proxy server/firewall like iptables or there is another way.

All best,
Angel

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to have everything going trough the same IP address ? the purpose of MX and SRV records are precisely to let you move email and SIP to different machines...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply add additional host entries to your domain, like sip.yourdomain.com, mail.yourdomain.com etc, each pointing to the relevant server? It's a better solution than with some redirection, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but time is pressing. Updating this domain would take several days and I want to get this thing running faster.

Comment: Updating the domain - by adding new A records for example - shouldn't take any time at all

Answer (score 0):

redir.  That will do what you want.  However SvenW is right.  You should just update dns as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I want to redirect UDP as well. IPTABLES cames in mind, I have never used it. Can it do the job?

Comment: Yep, iptables can certainly do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your outward facing server is Linux you should be running an iptables firewall on it.  Shorewall is the one I use.  It comes with example configurations for various situations.  Its documentation covers forwarding from the firewall to appropriate servers.  It also covers redirecting muliple IP addresses from the firewall to servers behind it. See the documentation at http://www.shorewall.net/